# How to construct the strong solution to the SDE $dX_{t}=\sqrt{X_{t}}dW_{t}$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Given the SDE: $dX_{t}=\sqrt{X_{t}}dW_{t},$ $\ X_{0}=1$ , where $W_{t}$ is a 1-d Brownian motion.

I was told that this SDE has a unique strong solution, but I don't know how to construct it. I know that this SDE has strong uniqueness, therefore I only need to construct a weak solution. I'm guessing we need to first consider a weak solution up to an explosion time (i.e. the hitting time of $X_{t}$ to the level $0$), but how to show such a weak solution exists?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check this: $X_t  = (\frac{1}{2}(W_t-W_0)+1)^2$

Comment: @nikita2 This would satisfy $\mathrm{d}X_t = \frac{1}{4} \mathrm{d}t + \sqrt{X_t} \mathrm{d}W_t$.

Comment: @Sasha Ok I just thought about PDE with separated variables.

Comment: Wouldn't a solution to this SDE be negative for some $t$ with positive probability? And isn't that a problem when looking at $\sqrt{X_t}$?

Comment: How do you know a strong solution exists? $\sqrt{x}$ is not Lipschitz at $0$.

Comment: @Michael You only need Holder-$1/2$ for the diffusive term in 1D SDE's. See for instance Section 3 in chapter IX of Revuz and Yor.

Answer (score 1):

This is follows from the beautiful result by Yamada-Watanabe in Shreve-Karatzas proposition 5.15

For $ X_t= \int_{0}^t a(s,X_s) dW_s + \int_{0}^t b(s,X_s) ds , t \in[0,T]$, the Yamada-Watanabe criterion states that if:

- $b$ is Lipschitz and
- there exists $h : \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$ strictly increasing continuous such that
- $h(0)=0$
- $\int_{x - \epsilon}^{x + \epsilon} \dfrac{dy}{ h^2(y) }= \infty, \forall \epsilon >0$
- $ |a(t,x) - a(t,y)| \leq h(x-y)$

Then we have existence and strong uniqueness.

With $\alpha \geq \frac12$ and   $a(t,x)= x^{\alpha}$ the conditions are verified.